# Android notifications does not disappear after click

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a piece of code on my android studio project:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        // .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("New updates from StoriesCity!")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

It's working fine and i see the notification, but when i click on it it does not go away..

Maybe it's because i'm using .notify ?
Please help me modify the code to makeit disapeair on click.

I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.setAutoCancel(true);
```

> [setAutoCancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setAutoCancel%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Set flag `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` instead of `0`

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Also

```
.setAoutoCancel(true)
```